# Java Web-Based Firewall Authenticate

Tags: java, post, firewall

Everyday, I have to go through a web based authentication system (firewall) which works likes this:
Once I am connected to the network and I type in any web address say `www.google.com`, I am presented with a web based login form (typing any address brings up the same form)
and after submit I get a Authenticated response page from the router with address:
`192.168.2.254:1000/keepalive?somejibberjabbernumberwhichchangeseverytime`

The page must be refreshed after 200 seconds or else you are logged out. This is done automatically but sometimes it fails.

After that, Internet is enabled and one can browse. I want to make a simple application (java) which does this boring task for me. 
It will send in my credentials to the server. Log me in. Send refresh command after say 30 seconds automatically.

Are there any suggestions as to how to do this? I need to create a standalone desktop application not a server-side app.

Thanks

Comment: A cheap way is to use a browser plugin that refreshes the page every N seconds. You will still need to enter your credentials...

Comment: This just seems like a bad idea, the idea of the firewall is to stop unauthorised access from scripts and people alike. Also, it sounds like this is at a place of work and such the log-in will likely be to monitor your internet usage, having a script do it for you could cause trouble with log-out/in meaning you log excessive hours online.

Comment: @Sean Kenny after 3 days of brain storming my application ready! happy surfing yipeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you want to "play browser" with your application? Web testing libraries like [httpunit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/) are well suited for such tasks. Basically, that's what you would do:

- Query some page (GetMethodWebRequest), expect to be redirected
- Check you're being redirected
- Extract the form (response.getFormWithID), fill in your credentials, submit it
- Most likely the tricky part: Get the popup window URL.
- Periodically poll the extracted URL

Have a look at httpunit's cookbook and tutorial, my guess would be that you find all information required for your problem there.

Comment: I am facing the following problems

Comment: I am trying out httpunit for the job. facing the following problems
there are some hidden values in the form some number changing everytime INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="magic" VALUE="061fd1c034ef429a" apart from the user/pass. can you please provide me a code which parses the page and finds the magic number and then submit user/pass/magic number. much appreciated thanxx

Comment: urladdr=response.getLastHeader("Location").getValue() is not able to fetch me the web addess as the address is like 192.168... but if i try wid wesite having a name it works! am using this coz html unit requies a form name my page doesnt have it